# SQL server 2008: Conversion of varchar to datetime failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have problems with the following code:

```
USE [PCIPNY];

insert into [dbo].[test_Drug_Medication_1]
(
       [MedicationID] ,[ClinicID] ,[PatientID] ,[MyDrugID] ,[NDC] ,[DoctorID] ,[DrugID] ,[DrugFullDesc] ,[Generic_Name]
      ,[Print_Name] ,[Manufacture] ,[Inactive_Date] ,[Strength] ,[Units] ,[Pkg_Size] ,[Pkg_Type] ,[Route] ,[Take]
      ,[Frequency] ,[Duration] ,[Qualifier] ,[Quantity] ,[Refill] ,[Note] ,[DAW] ,[CreateDate] ,[CreateBy]
      ,[ModifyBy],[IsControl] ,[UserDefine] ,[scheduleLevel] ,[BeginDate] ,[EndDate] ,[Active] ,[sente]
      ,[OnCologyCheckStatus] ,[OnCologyCheckStatus1] ,[OnCologyCheckStatus2] ,[SIG] ,[Printed] ,[ICDCode] ,[SendeFaxed] ,[DosageForm] ,[GPI]
      ,[IsBrand] ,[IsGeneric] ,[GenericAndBrand] ,[SigUnit] ,[IsDrug] ,[Status]
)

SELECT
      [MedicationID] ,[ClinicID] ,[PatientID] ,[MyDrugID] ,[NDC] ,[DoctorID] ,[DrugID] ,[DrugFullDesc] ,[Generic_Name]
      ,[Print_Name] ,[Manufacture] ,[Inactive_Date] ,[Strength] ,[Units] ,[Pkg_Size] ,[Pkg_Type] ,[Route] ,[Take]
      ,[Frequency] ,[Duration] ,[Qualifier] ,[Quantity] ,[Refill] ,[Note] ,[DAW] ,[CreateDate] ,[CreateBy]
      ,[ModifyBy] ,[IsControl] ,[UserDefine] ,[scheduleLevel] ,[BeginDate] ,[EndDate] ,[Active] ,[sente]
      ,[OnCologyCheckStatus] ,[OnCologyCheckStatus1] ,[OnCologyCheckStatus2] ,[SIG] ,[Printed] ,[ICDCode] ,[SendeFaxed] ,[DosageForm] ,[GPI]
      ,[IsBrand] ,[IsGeneric] ,[GenericAndBrand] ,[SigUnit] ,[IsDrug] ,[Status]

  FROM [ec14].[dbo].[Drug_Medication]
    where 1=1
      and clinicid in (select clinicid from [dbo].[clinic] where org_db = 'ec14' and ClinicID=1234);
```

I got this error:

> > Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
> >     Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I found out that the error is in the column `begindate`.

The column `begindate` in ec04(origin location) is `charvar(16)` datatype.
The column `begindate` in PCIPNY(destination location) is `datetime` datatype.

Is there any solution to make this work?

Comment: And what will you do with invalid dates?

Answer (score 1):

In the SELECT clause from source, change

```
BeginDate
```

To

```
CASE WHEN ISDATE(BeginDate) = 1 then CAST(BeginDate AS DATETIME) END
```

It is a case of not setting the DMY/MDY format correct?  You can try changing [SET DATEFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx).  Or are all the dates (in varchar) in a specific format that can actually be converted?  If so you can use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with a format specifier.

```
CONVERT(datetime, BeginDate, 103)
```

Answer (score 0):

try casting the field you select from ec14..

`, cast(begindate as datetime) ,`

Comment: SQL Server will do the cast implicitly. That's why the conversion error comes up!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the date is in the correct format, or that the columns didn't get shifted. I've had this error before when the order of the columns being inserted is wrong. It's possible the data attempting to go into the date field is not the date and another field.